# Find out unique categories in all categorical variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, categorical-data

can someone help me to find the number of observations in each different category in variables using python? for that i used

```
df['column name'].value_counts() for single variable.
```

But I want to know how it uses for whole categorical variables in data-set.

Comment: can you add more examples of how your data looks like?

Comment: [pandas describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) can give you the number of unique categories .

Comment: Thanks @Shijith i'm not find points from pandas describe regarding my question. and i made some changes my question.

Comment: @Sampath what  you mean more example??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about looping through dataset having categorical columns only, and then printing unique values?

```
df_ = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int', 'float'])
for col in df_.columns:
    print(df_[col].unique()) # to print categories name only
    print(df_[col].value_counts()) # to print count of every category
```

Comment: Please look again Quection i made some edit it.

Comment: Thanks @Shweta Chandel your help.  I run your code then i got following error. Why its happened.         AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'columns

Comment: @randunugalhena I have made a little correction. Please check.

Comment: Thanks..code is now work..can i know what correction did u made? for just my knowledge.

Comment: @randunugalhena removed .columns from first line. Can you accept it as answer if it qualifies for it?

Comment: Ok @Sheweta Chandel I already did it.